# Error while deploying the Tomcat server into Eclipse

Tags: java, tomcat6

I am trying to deploy Tomcat into the eclipse. While doing so, I am getting the following message:

> Deployment failure on Tomcat  6.x. Could not copy all resources to C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\web. If a file is locked, you can wait until the lock times out to redeploy, or stop the server and redeploy, or manually remove the deployment at C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\web

Can any one help me out?

Comment: when am deploying the tom cat its not running.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, this error usually means that eclipse wants to delete a file or directory and windows won't let it.  This is usually because tomcat is still running, or there is a command prompt or explorer window open in the deployment directory or one of its subdirectories.

Use Windows Task Manager to verify that tomcat is not still running, and make sure you don't have any command prompts or explorer windows open in the deployment directory.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don´t have write access to Tomcats program directory?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to copy tomcat in a different location. It could be that the spaces in your tomcat path causing these problems. 
Choose something like c:\tomcat6*

Answer (score 0):

Stop the tomcat server,  undeploy your app by choosing ' add and remove projects', go to webapps folder, delete the  folder 'web', redeploy your app and restart tomcat server. That should do it.

Answer (score -1):

This is generally happening when You are Importing project from somewhere else or Checking out from SVN.
The solution is in Eclipse jar file referenced in the project to re-add it again on the line, the basic reason is that the jar file does not exist, there project information, project classpath files still do not exist jar file references.

You can right-point project name, select Properties, select Java Build Path, select Libraries are a remove all items in the jar, and then point to "add jars", add to the mix jar file in the project, again deploy to normal.